# Why does Augmented Matrix let us to ditch the variables (e.g. x, y, z, ...)?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

Say we have e.g. the system of linear equations:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1\\0&-1&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

Why does Augmented Matrix let us ditch \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} in order to get:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&0&1&1\\
      0&-1&0&2\\
      1&0&1&3
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Does this hold for non-linear systems of equations as well?

Comment: I suggest you to study first chapter of Linear Algebra - Hoffman and Kunze

Comment: @RaziehNoori Or this note: http://www.pstcc.edu/math/_files/pdf/augment.pdf To see that the system is truly the same.

Comment: It is very simple. Think of how you solve a non-homogeneous system of equations.

Comment: I got what you want to know. be sure if you study that book I said, you will understand its reason. It is only a little long for writting :D (using product of elementary matrices,....)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write the name of the variable any more as in the matrix each row represents the coefficient of the variables. So if you can reduce a row to only one single 1 and all other entries of the row to 0. then basically you get the value of the corresponding variable on the right hand side.

For example: as you got the 2nd entry in the 2md row to be -1 you can directly say that the value of y is -2.